# How to express in German key something?

Tags: word-usage, noun

In English we place the word **key** in front of a word to show the importance of the terms, every branch has its own key words. For example for the sake of this site  *German, grammar, online German language forum etc.*  might be key words. But translators translate **key word** to **Stichwort**, so which should I place at the beginning of the terms: **Stich-** or **Schlüssel-**?

Could you please provide the correct usage of **Stich**/**Schlüssel** and show the difference?

> Schlüsselwort/Stichwort
>
> Schlüsselstrategie/Stichstrategie
>
> Schlüsselinformation/Stichinformation

Comment: Did you try to look your German constructions up in a dictionary? Why not?

Comment: I'd just like to note that *key ...* could also translate to *Haupt...*. For example the *key feature* or some software could be the *Hauptfunktionalität* or *Hauptmerkmal*.

Answer (score 7):

A **Schlüssel** (*key*) is something that unlocks something, both in a literal and in a figurative sense.

So if you are talking about reveiling, gaining access or unveiling something, the compounds with **Schlüssel-** are the way to go:

You may unlock a market (**Schlüsseltechnologie**), have an ability that gives you access to a certain job (**Schlüsselfertigkeit**) or a knowledge that allows you deduce the complete information (**Schlüsselinformation**) etc.

BUT there is a concurrent, possibly older concept in the German language using the term **Stich**, which means *sting* or *stab* and has a plethora of uses, in the figurative sense often something along the lines of "pick one element (or a few elements) to represent the entity".

The [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/cache/shortcuts/Stichwort.html) writes for **Stichwort** :

> 1. Wort, das in einem Lexikon, Wörterbuch behandelt wird, *Stichwörter*
>      -> dieses Wörterbuch enthält zehntausend Stichwörter
> 2. Wort, auf das hin ein Schauspieler einsetzen oder auftreten muss *-e*
>      -> jmdm. für seinen Einsatz das Stichwort geben
>      *übertragen*
>      -> das war das Stichwort für einen Streit, der nun ausbrach
> 3. Wort als Hilfe, sich etw. zu merken *-e; meist im Plural*
>      -> er notierte einige Stichworte für seinen Vortrag

And as origin:

> **Stichwort** n.
>
> - ‘stechendes, verletzendes Wort’ (15. Jh.),
> - ‘für einen bestimmten Zweck aus einem Zusammenhang herausgenommenes Wort, letztes Wort eines Schauspielers, nach dem ein anderer einsetzt’ (18. Jh.),
> - ‘Lemma, behandeltes Wort in Lexika’, im Plural ‘Anhaltspunkte, Gedanken für den Aufbau einer Rede, eines Aufsatzes’ (19. Jh.),
> - in den letztgenannten modernen Verwendungen im Sinne von ‘hervorstechendes, herausgestochenes Wort’.

So while in English *keyword* can mean "secret word to unlock something" and "word to represent an entity", in German you have to distinguish between a **Schlüsselwort** and **Stichwort** - [the latter being the more frequent one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Stichwort%2C%20Schl%C3%BCsselwort&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CStichwort%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CSchl%C3%BCsselwort%3B%2Cc0).

Note that **Schlüsselwort** is a *keyword* in the sense of unlocking a secret (a password) while a **Stichwort** is used to structure Information or trigger an action.

Comment: Could you please add a reference for your interpretation of "Schlüsselwort" as password? I wouldn't understand it this way.

Answer (score 2):

**The English word *key* does not have a perfect German counterpart.**

That is the *key* issue here. I could think up a few *key* cases and present you the *key* results. You may then find a few *key* words but the *key* message should also be clear: That the key’s *key* concept is lost in translation.

> Das ist hier der *springende Punkt*. Ich könnte mir ein paar *wichtige* Fälle überlegen und dir davon die *Schlüssel*ergebnisse präsentieren. Du könntest dann ein paar *Stich*wörter/*Schlüssel*wörter darin finden, aber die *Haupt*nachricht sollte deutlich sein: Der *Kern* des Konzepts ist in der Übersetzung verschollen.

(I’ll admit that both the English mock-up and the translation are not perfect. You can probably word quite a few things better and also use *Schlüssel-* in more contexts. However, *Schlüssel-* will never actually reach the versatility of *key* — which is my key point.)

Answer (score 1):

Well for the first pair i think @oberflansch gave a good explanation.

> Schlüsselwort/Stichwort

So I'll try to give some more "help" for the 2 other pairs:

> Schlüsselstrategie/Stichstrategie
>
> Schlüsselinformation/Stichinformation

First I'd say that i never heard or read the "Prefix" "Stich-" in that context.
But a few other examples that work could be

> Stichtag = appointed date/key date
>
> Stichpunkt = headword

---

> Stichproben = spot test, random samples (No relation to "key something", emphasizes randomness)
>
> stichhaltig = valid/sound/cogent
>
> and stichprobenartig

A theory that came to my mind, maybe it could be helpful:

**Stich** usually means stab/sting etc. so it refers to something one would/should remember because of the effect and this somehow doesn't apply for a Strategy or an Information.

While **Schlüssel** usually points at something that lead to success or a decisive change.
I would like to explain some of those words according to my explained interpretation:

- Stichwort = Refers to a word one should remember, maybe because it's important or significant ...
- Stichpunkt (Stichpunkte) = Are points one wants to remember. Example you are holding a speech and you don't want to forget a couple of points then you mark them to remember them!
- Schlüsselstrategie = would mean the strategy which lead to success or to a significant decision!
- Schlüsselinformation = could mean the most important Information (->success) or the missing Information (->significant, decisive)
- Schlüsselwort = Is an important word so it's at least significant in the context, and as a word like that also should be remembered there's a link to Stichwort!